# how to save image path by using mysql and python language

Tags: python, mysql, image

with not using php ,
after getting image path from client part , i want to save it into mysql ... 
how to write mysql query .... i do not know what kind of type i have to use when i save file path where the image saved in my computer memory. 
i just need to load my image and store image path to my computer(C://) not using web condition , php . 
i think it is very easy so that could not find google or this site.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  number INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  imagepath (whattype)(size) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to save the path then it should be `VARCHAR(255)`

You can increase the size depending on your needs. The file path can have very long names.

Comment: What makes you think `VARCHAR(50)` will be long enough? That seems entirely arbitrary. [Windows file paths can be at least 260 characters long](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx), and "The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of 32,767 characters".

Comment: `VARCHAR(255)` probably still isn't enough. Please make sure to research the maximum size your input data can possibly have before deciding on data types, especially when answering other users' questions on SO.

Comment: I guess TEXT can handle it